# BigQuery automatically converts timestamp timezone to UTC

Tags: python, timezone, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table as such:

[image]

and a file as such: https://storage.googleapis.com/test_share_file/testTimestamp.csv

which looks like: 
[image]

and I load the file to big query using python as such:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq

gs_path = 'gs://test_share_file/testTimestamp.csv'
bq_client = bq.Client.from_service_account_json(gcp_creds_fp)
ds = bq_client.dataset('test1')
tbl = ds.table('testTimestamp')

job_config = bq.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = bq.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1 # skip header
load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(gs_path, tbl, job_config=job_config)
res = load_job.result()
```

and yet in the table, both timestamps are in UTC time!

[image]

How do I get the second column to be in eastern time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "transform" first column into eastern time on-fly - something like in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-05-07 22:40:00+00:00' AS ts
)
SELECT ts, STRING(ts, '-04:00') timestamp_eastern
FROM t
```

> I am dealing with ... stubbornness ...

You can create view which will consists of all the logic you need in place so client will query that view instead of original table

```
#standardSQL
CREATE VIEW `project.dataset.your_view` AS 
SELECT ts, STRING(ts, '-04:00') timestamp_eastern 
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
```

> I do think it odd that big query can't display a time in a timezone

*A timestamp represents an absolute point in time, independent of any time zone or convention such as Daylight Savings Time.

Time zones are used when parsing timestamps or formatting timestamps for display. The timestamp value itself does not store a specific time zone. A string-formatted timestamp may include a time zone. When a time zone is not explicitly specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used.*

See more about [`Timestamp type`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type)

Comment: Do big query _cannot_ have a column that is in a timezone other than utc?

Comment: I ask because the client using this database does not know sql and I've been asked to have the timezone in eastern by default.

Comment: Timestamps store a point in time relative to the Unix epoch; they don't encode a time zone. When you convert the timestamp to a another type, such as string, date, datetime, or time, either you specify the time zone that you want to use for the conversion, or use the default, which is UTC.

Comment: @RSHAP - I second Elliott and that is why I think my answer is still the way for you to go. As of `client ... does not know sql` - you should apply some extra efforts to teach/educate client with at least some basics otherwise you will have problem later on anyway. not knowing Sql nowadays is like totally not knowing basic English. So if this client important for you - make it happen :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I appreciate the thought and I agree and will try to help them learn basic sql. I also agree that this should not be a big deal for them to simply convert a column to a string. However, I am dealing with blinded stubbornness on their end unlike any I have ever known and I do think it odd that big query __can't__ display a time in a timezone.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I have also tried using a DATETIME column and it fails as unable to parse the time-offset string.

Comment: @RSHAP - understood. we all facing time by time that situation (client's stubbornness) if you can provide more details on your specific use case - we might be able to help more. mostly - how your client expects to use/consume the data if they are not willing to learn sql? etc. Meantime, see update I added in my answer

Comment: -04:00 is an offset from UTC, but is not a time zone.  Eastern Time in the US and Canada alternates between -05:00 and -04:00 for DST.  You need a way to specify a tzid like  `America/New_York` so it can decide which offset is in effect for each timestamp.  I'm not sure if that is supported in this environment or not.

Comment: It is. You can pass that as the time zone string.

Comment: 100% correct. to correctly represent timezone - timezone name should be used instead of hours difference. so it should be something like `STRING(ts, 'America/New_York')`. I just don't know exact OP case so wanted to be as close tohis original question as possible

Comment: @ElliottBrossard fyi - It still does not work with passing in a time zone string instead of offset:

`'message': "Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '2018-05-07 18:40:00 America/New_York' as datetime for field timestamp_eastern (position 2) starting at location 162"`

Comment: Datetime represents a logical time. If you want to parse with a time zone, parse as a timestamp.